# Need to have a custom field in salesforce object that will combine two other fields

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud

We have a requirement where we need to combine two separate fields into one in the salesforce object and then removed those separate fields from the page layout but when the edit option is enabled in the salesforce portal to edit the object the eliminated fields should be there for edit. If further clarification is required, I can also do that

Click here to see the screenshot

[image: 1]

I have tried the formula custom field type where I have to write a formula of concatenating the two fields like this given below:`Text(Rent_Start_Date_Actual__c) & ","& Text(Rent_Start_Date_Type__c)`. I have also removed these two separate fields from salesforce page layout but it also gets removed when object window is in edit mode and we do not want that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than potentially messing with the edit page, have you considered using a simple screen Flow and an action to achieve this? For example, an action to 'Edit Rent Details' added to the page header, and then when clicked it presents the individual fields on a screen flow for editing?  Once saved, the page would refresh and update the formula field as required.

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Please share any link regarding this @user1517566 it would be very helpful

Comment: Not able to implement this using screen flow , please recommend any link or article for help